# Этот метод повторяется в нескольких активити. Не получается оптимизировать? Попытался решить ч/з BaseActivity

Tags: java, android

-Повторяющийся код:

```
private void onFabHomeClickListener() {
    fab_home.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(GroomerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        GroomerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    });
}
```

-BaseActivity (как я пытался решить проблему):

```
public void onFabHomeClickListener(FloatingActionButton fab, Context context) {
    fab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    });
```

-Как я вызываю этот метод в наследуемом активити:

```
    BaseActivity baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
    baseActivity.onFabHomeClickListener(fab_home,GroomerActivity.this);
```

-Итог: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: причём тут метка singleton?

Comment: Тимур, вы можете помочь?

Comment: Укажите метку языка и что значит "оптимизировать"

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста описание метки "инспекция-кода", это вам поможет сформулировать ваш вопрос лучше

Comment: "инспекция-кода" - указал по ошибке.

Comment: "оптимизировать" значит написать код в одном классе, а не писать его как у меня сейчас в каждом активити.

Comment: Я создал BaseActivity. Унаследовался от данного класса.
И прописал следующий код:

        BaseActivity baseActivity = new BaseActivity();
        baseActivity.onFabHomeClickListener(fab_home,GroomerActivity.this);

Comment: Не нужно создавать экземпляр `BaseActivity` - наследник может вызывать его метод так же как свой собственный без указания объекта: `onFabHomeClickListener(fab_home,GroomerActivity.this);`

Answer (score 2):

Создаете класс, который реализует интерфейс `View.OnClickListener`, прописываете в нем логику кликов и будет вам счастье:

```
class FabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Вы можете скачать приложение по ссылке: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Поделиться приложением", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Далее в коде вы просто пишите

```
fab_home.setOnClickListener(new FabClickListener());
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @MederMalikovich, [Как отблагодарить за ответ на Stack Overflow?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/11515)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов:
**1.** Делаем его утилитарным (статическим) и используем везде вместо дубликатов:

```
public static void onFabClickListener(Activity activity, View fab) {
    fab.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Вы можете скачать приложение по ссылке: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Поделиться приложением", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
}
```

Желательно переместить его в отдельный класс с другими подобными методами.

---

**2.** Делаем базовый класс активности и реализуем в нём весь общий функционал, а активности, в которых этот функционал нужен наследуем от этого базового класса.

---

**3.** По сути сам метод и не нужен - можно вынести реализацию листенера в отдельный класс и назначать его кнопкам:

```
public class OnFabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Вы можете скачать приложение по ссылке: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Поделиться приложением", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

и везде вместо вызова того метода назначать наш листенер:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new OnFabClickListener());
```